# How can I view website requests in console in real time?

Tags: tools

I want to display incomming requests to my web server in real time, in console. Each request should be represented by a single line with information about the request, i.e. client’s IP address, etc.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: You can view server access log using standard Unix tools if you have privilege to view them. I would use something like `su -c 'tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log'`. The `su` command executes shell as another user (`root` by default) and `tail -f` displays last 10 lines of the file and keeps displaying more as they arrive.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you want this, @chris. Maybe then there will be a better answer. If you want to debug your server scripting code, maybe [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) will be a better fit for this question.

Comment: You can stream the log file using the command `less logfile.log` and press Shift + F and the file will stream so that you can read new request directly.